# htaccess redirect bad urls from google search console

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I've been running through my recent Google Search Console updates,
trying to work through & redirect any & all 404 pages found..

So 1 group of urls that are output like:

```
index.php?controller=new-products&%253B%253B%25253Bamp%25253B%25253B%25253B%2525253Bamp%2525253B%2525253B%2525253B%252525
```

the urls are huge & super long...
What I'm trying to do is redirect ALL urls with the above "controller=new-products" back to the homepage, but since all the urls have crazy query string values aplied to it, none of my htaccess directives seem to be working!

Test 1:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^controller=new-products.+$
RewriteRule ^/?$ /? [L,R]
```

test 2:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^controller=new-products&([0-9a-z_-]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /? [R=301,L]
```

test 3:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)controller=new-products(&|$)  [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/index\.php$ https://www.example.co.uk/? [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php? [L]
```

any help would be much appreciated!
thanks!

Comment: The RewriteCond of your first attempt should work perfectly fine already; but then in your RewriteRule you demand that the URL path should be empty or just a slash - which it of course isn't, when you got `index.php` in there.

Comment: hey CBroe, thanks for that, I  did re-test #1, like you mention, but still no joy!..
The htaccess file is rather large, with lots of old redirects, deflate & ExpiresByType

I've added the redirect at the top & the bottom of the file, still no luck. thanks!

Comment: What RewriteRule pattern did you use, did you modify it do match the index.php from the URL path? `^index\.php$`

Comment: "test 2" would not match the stated query string (`[0-9a-z_-]+` does not match `%253B%253B%25....`) and in "test 3" you appear to have introduced (what looks like) a check for a 2-char language code? (But then the directives that follow would seem to be irrelevant?)